# Writing a user defined function

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, 32-bit, irvine32

I don't know why this code won't work. I want to call a user define function in MASM. Do I need to define a prototype in the program?

Here is my code:

```
include Irvine32.inc
.code

     main proc
     call clrscr
     mov eax,60000h
     call sum1
     call dumpregs
     exit
main endp
end main
sum1 proc
    add eax,20000h
    ret
sum endp
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have prematurely ended your file by placing `end main` in the middle of your file instead of at the end:

```
main endp
end main
sum1 proc
    add eax,20000h
    ret
sum endp
```

Everything after `end main` will not emit code. Place `end main` at the end of your file. The `END` directive with a label will mark the end of the file and tell the assembler that the entry point where code will start execution is at the label `main`.

Your code could look like:

```
include Irvine32.inc
.code

main proc
     call clrscr
     mov eax,60000h
     call sum1
     call dumpregs
     exit
main endp
sum1 proc
    add eax,20000h
    ret
sum endp
end main
```

Your original code will likely cause `sum1` to appear as not being defined to the linker. I would expect the linker to inform you that the function `sum1` couldn't be found.